# $.ajax Get data does not append to var

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I ve a problem with the output:i want to fill the ouptput whit some data from an ajaxcall.
the call is successfull(the output inside the each is filled with data)
but the output inside the each issnt apended to the output outside .
i always geht "

```
<ul id="listname" data-inset=true></ul>
```

and not

```
  <ul id="listname" data-inset=true><li>some data</li></ul>
```

```
$("div:jqmData(role='collapsible')").each(function(){
var id = $(this).data("id");
     var idDate=id.slice(7,18);
     var listapp="id_col_"+idDate;
      var listname="id_col_"+idDate;
                   output='<ul id="listname" data-inset=true>';

                             $.ajax({
                             url: 'lomodata.php',
                             data: 'timestamp='+idDate,
                             type: 'GET',
                             ContentType: "application/json",
                             dataType: "json",
                             success:function(res) {
                             if(res !='')
                            {
                            $.each(res, function(i, Object) {
                             output+='<li>'+Object.reg+'</li>';
                              console.log(output);
                            }); 
                             }
                             }

                             });

                    output+='</ul>';

                    $(this).append(output).trigger("create");
                    $(this).listview();
                    $(this).listview('refresh');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is Asynchronous. When you write `$.ajax( ... )`, an HTTP request will be sent to the server, which will then move on to the next operation, `output += '</ul>'`. The HTTP request will not have finished by this time, and so your callback will not yet have been executed by the time you append `output` to the document.

Answer (score 2):

Note that `$.ajax` is by default **asynchronous**, and by the time you reach `$(this).append(output)`, `output` is not yet defined, since the `.ajax()` call hasn't finished yet. You need to move the `append` to the `success` handler, or add the `async: false` option, so that `$.ajax` becomes a blocking call (although this defeats the purpose of using `ajax`):

```
success: function(res) {
  if (res !='') {
    var output='<ul id="listname" data-inset=true>';
    $.each(res, function(i, Object) {
      output+='<li>'+Object.reg+'</li>';
      console.log(output);
    });
    output+='</ul>';
    $(this).append(output).trigger("create");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div:jqmData(role='collapsible')").each(function () {
  var el = this;
  var id = $(this).data("id");
  var idDate = id.slice(7, 18);
  var listapp = "id_col_" + idDate;
  var listname = "id_col_" + idDate;

  $.ajax({
    url: 'lomodata.php',
    data: 'timestamp=' + idDate,
    type: 'GET',
    ContentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (res) {
      output = '<ul id="listname" data-inset=true>';

      if (res != '') {
        $.each(res, function (i, Object) {
          output += '<li>' + Object.reg + '</li>';
          console.log(output);
        });
      }

      output += '</ul>';

      el.append(output).trigger("create");
      el.listview();
      el.listview('refresh');
    }

  });
});
```

Comment: the output (ul) has to be befor the ajax call, as i do not want a sublist of the entrys

Answer (score 0):

If you move all lines of codes that use the `output` variable to the success function of the ajax call, you will see that it works. The problem is that you're using asynchronicity incorrectly.

Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'lomodata.php',
 data: 'timestamp=' + idDate,
 type: 'GET',
 ContentType: "application/json",
 dataType: "json",
 success: function (res) {
   if (res != '') {
    var output = '<ul id="listname" data-inset=true>';
    $.each(res, function (i, Object) {
       output += '<li>' + Object.reg + '</li>';
     });
    output += '</ul>';

    console.log(output);

    $("#myObject").append(output).trigger("create");
    $("#myObject").listview();
    $("#myObject").listview('refresh');
  }
}
```

});